# Spring c-namespace issue - Constructor argument '_street' specifies an invalid integer

Tags: spring

I am trying out the use of c-namespace while injecting literal values into a constructor. I am running into an issue if I refer to the constructor argument by its name. If I refer to it by the position (i.e. 0,1,2...) it works perfectly fine.

I have set the variable debugging check in eclipse (I am using STS) - Windows > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Add variable attributes to generated class files but I still see the same issue

Below is my code -

Interface

```
package com.nilaysundarkar.spring.demos;

public interface Person {
public void speak();
}
```

Implementation

```
package com.nilaysundarkar.spring.demos;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNameAware;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Component
@Named("Russland")
public class Russian implements Person, BeanNameAware {

private String language = "Russian";
private Address address;

@Autowired
public Russian(Address address){
    this.address = address;
}

public void speak() {
    System.out.println("I am a Person. I speak " + language + ".");
    System.out.println("I stay at " + address + ".");
}

public void setBeanName(String beanName) {
    System.out.println(beanName + " has been initialized.");
}

}
```

Address class

```
package com.nilaysundarkar.spring.demos;

public class Address {

private String street;

public Address(String street){
    this.street = street;
}

public String toString(){
    return street;
}

}
```

Bootstrapping the context -

```
package com.nilaysundarkar.spring.demos;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
    Person person = context.getBean(Person.class);
    person.speak();
    ((FileSystemXmlApplicationContext) context).close();
}

}
```

beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.nilaysundarkar.spring.demos"/>


<!-- Works -->
<!--<bean id="address" class="com.nilaysundarkar.spring.demos.Address" c:_0="200 Baker Street" />-->


<!-- Does'nt Work -->
<bean id="address" class="com.nilaysundarkar.spring.demos.Address" c:_street="200 Baker Street" />

</beans>
```

Error when run with c:_street -

```
Mar 25, 2017 1:39:44 PM org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@179d3b25: startup date [Sat Mar 25 13:39:44 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Mar 25, 2017 1:39:44 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from file [C:\Users\Nilay\Documents\workspace-sts-3.8.3.RELEASE\demos\beans.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Constructor argument '_street' specifies an invalid integer
Offending resource: file [C:\Users\Nilay\Documents\workspace-sts-3.8.3.RELEASE\demos\beans.xml]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:72)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.SimpleConstructorNamespaceHandler.decorate(SimpleConstructorNamespaceHandler.java:111)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.decorateIfRequired(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1448)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.decorateBeanDefinitionIfRequired(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1427)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.decorateBeanDefinitionIfRequired(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1415)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.processBeanDefinition(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:169)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:142)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:613)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:514)
at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
at com.nilaysundarkar.spring.demos.App.main(App.java:9)
```

When run with c:_0

```
Mar 25, 2017 1:42:35 PM org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@179d3b25: startup date [Sat Mar 25 13:42:35 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Mar 25, 2017 1:42:35 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from file [C:\Users\Nilay\Documents\workspace-sts-3.8.3.RELEASE\demos\beans.xml]
Mar 25, 2017 1:42:36 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor <init>
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
Russland has been initialized.
I am a Person. I speak Russian.
I stay at 200 Baker Street.
Mar 25, 2017 1:42:36 PM org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@179d3b25: startup date [Sat Mar 25 13:42:35 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
```

pom.xml -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.nilaysundarkar.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>demos</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Did you try `c:street` instead of `c:_street`?

Comment: that made it work. I guess its a typo in the book - Spring in Action. Thanks!

Comment: Reposted as answer to make it more visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way would be to use `c:street` and not `c:_street`, as the value after `c:` prefix must match the constructor parameter name.